# Deleting and editing messages/embeds with discord components

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've been messing around with components recently... As of right now I am trying to make two separate components do something to the message they are applied to.
`Delete` deletes the message
`Approve` edits the message (which is an embed) and does nothing more.
As you see, the message I've applied these components to is called `firstmessage`.

It works, yes, but there is one slight problem...

If there are f.ex two of these `firstmessage` embeds in separate messages, and I click `Delete` on one, they both get deleted. The same applies to them both when I click `Approve` on one. This is about the only problem I have right now.

Code:

```
firstmessage = await channel.send(
embed=firstembed,
components=[[Button(style=3, label="Approve"),Button(style=4, label="Delete")]
])

interaction = await self.bot.wait_for("button_click")

if interaction.component.label.startswith("Approve"):
    await firstmessage.edit(embed=approved, components=[]) # here I edit firstmessage upon clicking
    pass

elif interaction.component.label.startswith("Delete"):
    await firstmessage.delete() # here I delete firstmessage upon clicking
    pass
```

Help and tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Discord Python button press triggers all buttons in a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68692198/discord-python-button-press-triggers-all-buttons-in-a-command/68707428#68707428)

I answered this question. Your question is similar to this.

In your situation you should change your code to:

```py
firstmessage = await channel.send(
embed=firstembed,
components=[[Button(style=3, label="Approve"),Button(style=4, label="Delete")]
])
# The following code is new
def check(res):
  return res.message = firstmessage # Checks if the message sent is the message that was interacted
# The above code is new
interaction = await self.bot.wait_for("button_click",check=check)

if interaction.component.label.startswith("Approve"):
    await firstmessage.edit(embed=approved, components=[]) # here I edit firstmessage upon clicking
    pass

elif interaction.component.label.startswith("Delete"):
    await firstmessage.delete() # here I delete firstmessage upon clicking
    pass
```