# Discord Python button press triggers all buttons in a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a bot for Discord in Python. However I am running into an issue with the newly added buttons. The issue is as follows: I use a command multiple times and this results into multiple embeds with buttons, however when I press the button in one of the embeds, the button with the same label in the other embed is also triggered.

The behaviour I would like to have is having the button only triggering in the embed that is being clicked on.

The code I have is

```
async def open(ctx):
    def check(res):
        return ctx.author == res.user and res.channel == ctx.channel
    blue = ["Possibly", "No"]
    blueresult = random.choice(blue)
    em = discord.Embed(title= f"Congratulations!",description =f"The result is **{blueresult}**!",color = discord.Color.blue())

    yes = Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Yes")
    no = Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="No")
    m = await ctx.send(embed = em,components=[[no,yes]])
    res = await client.wait_for("button_click", check=check)
    user = res.component.label

    if player=="Yes":
        await m.edit(embed=em,components=[])
    elif player=="No":
        await m.edit(embed=em,components=[])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the check function to:

```py
def check(res):
    return ctx.author == res.user and res.channel == ctx.channel and m == res.message
```

But you have to place it under this piece of code:

```py
yes = Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Yes")
no = Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="No")
m = await ctx.send(embed = em,components=[[no,yes]])
```

So the result should be:

```py
yes = Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Yes")
no = Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="No")
m = await ctx.send(embed = em,components=[[no,yes]])
def check(res):
    return ctx.author == res.user and res.channel == ctx.channel and m == res.message
```

The new code checks if the embed message the bot sent is the responded message. I tested it, and it worked for me.

Comment: @Richardx_ No problem!